# JavaScript Executor not working when running Executable JAR file

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, automation, executable-jar

When I run the test case in Eclipse, everything works fine, but when I make executable .jar of it, it runs until the command

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

It returns java.lang.NullPointerException at this line of code

If there is another way to scroll element into view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run from Eclipse IDE, the Run Configuration automatically adds the library you depend on (defined in your Eclipse project if not using another dependency management technology) to the classpath. So in this case, it succeeds at instantiating properly the `js` variable.

When not in Eclipse IDE, you have to specify the classpath to the command line in order to include dependencies. Otherwise, the dependencies are missing and you don't get a good way to instantiate the `js` object.